# i want to make app post to wall automatically using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i want a code that post to wall and

1- don't need a button that user has to click on

2- permissions appear automatically when user first go to app

3- i don't want a popup window to appear

Comment: And I want some ice-cream. And a sports car. And $1 Billion in small, not consecutively numbered used bills. Oh, and _you_ want to read the FAQ, especially http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Open Graph tutorial.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

You ask for permission to publish things only once.